# What does the XXXXXX in an sprintf format argument of "/tmp/%s-XXXXXX" mean?

Tags: c++, printf

In the following code, it seems XXXXXX asks to generate random characters to replace it.
What does XXXXXX mean here? Is this some special reserved symbol in `sprintf`?

```
sprintf(tempName, "/tmp/%s-XXXXXX", filename.c_str());
```

Comment: The `"XXXXXX"` is not a [`sprintf` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), so it must be text for the User.

Comment: @Mike "XXXXXX" literally means "XXXXXX".:)

Comment: The code fragment is C++, C tag removed.  However you might simplify the fragment to make it valid in both.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More context would help, but judging from the array name `tempName`, this `sprintf` call is probably composing a template for use with `mktemp()`, `mkstemp()`, `mkdtemp()` or a similar function.

The `X`s do not have any particular meaning for `sprintf`, but are interpreted by the next function called with `tempName`.

These POSIX functions are declared in `<unistd.h>`:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> char *mktemp(char *template);
> int mkstemp(char *template);
> char *mkdtemp(char *template);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `mktemp()` function takes the given file name template and overwrites a portion of it to create a file name.
>
> This file name is guaranteed not to exist at the time of function invocation and is suitable for use by the application.  The template may be any file name with some number of `X`s appended to it, for example `/tmp/temp.XXXXXX`.  The trailing `X`s are replaced with a unique alphanumeric combination.  The number of unique file names `mktemp()` can return depends on the number of `X`s provided; six `X`s will result in `mktemp()` selecting one of 56800235584 (62<sup>6</sup>) possible temporary file names.
>
> The `mkstemp()` function makes the same replacement to the template and creates the template file, mode 0600, returning a file descriptor opened for reading and writing. This avoids the race between testing for a file's existence and opening it for use.
>
> The `mkdtemp()` function makes the same replacement to the template as in `mktemp()` and creates the template directory, mode 0700.

Note that unless `tempName` was allocated with enough space for `filename.c_str()` plus 12 characters and a null terminator, using `snprintf()` is highly recommended to avoid undefined behavior, and limit the number of characters from `filename.c_str()` to make sure all `X`s are present at the end:

```c
char tempname[32];
snprintf(tempName, sizeof tempName, "/tmp/%.19s-XXXXXX", filename.c_str());
```